# Change size of my partition

Tags: partitioning, resize

I would like to change the size of my ubuntu partition /dev/sda8. I am in this configuration: [image: My config]

Unhappily, I can not manually use the unallocated memory of 56 GB. Hence I have two questions : why? And how can I use this available memory to increase my partition's size anyway?

Comment: You need do boot from LiveCD and move other partitions. You can't just "use" unallocated space. You can only extend a partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Note that, to use the first available space, you must first resize the extended partition that contains all the logical partitions. If you want to create *one* new partition that occupies all the available free space, you must move several partitions. Alternatively, you could create two partitions and use them in an [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) setup.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The problem is not how to use gparted. That is my bad, I did not explain my problem very clearly. My actual problem is that I can not reallocate the unallocated memory to /dev/sda8 nor /dev/sda9. When I try to resize these two partitions, the software does not give my the possibility to give it more space, even if I have dozens of unallocated GigaBytes elsewhere on my hard-drive. I do not understand why and how to deal with this issue. Thank you all again.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

1. Boot from a LiveUSB or CD in "Try Ubuntu" mode.
2. Open Gparted partiotion editor (It is installed by default. If not you can install it by using the command `sudo apt-get install gparted`)
3. Resize your partitions.

   - Right click on the partition to be resized

     Click on Resize/Move

     Adjust the size of the partition

     Click Resize/Move
4. Click apply.
5. Reboot and take out the USB stick or CD.

You can also do this by using [Gparted live](https://gparted.sourceforge.io/download.php).